# Updating build.gradle removes libraries from classpath

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have created spring mvc project with gradle and I have the following problem.

I know solution of this problem is simple but I haven't found it yet.

this is code in HibernateConfiguration.java:

[image]

this is `build.gradle` file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

group 'com.gtu.gtesting'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    //---
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name:'spring-core', version:'5.1.2.RELEASE'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name:'spring-tx', version:'5.1.2.RELEASE'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name:'spring-beans', version:'5.1.2.RELEASE'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name:'spring-orm', version:'5.1.2.RELEASE'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-mvc', version: '5.1.2.RELEASE'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '5.1.2.RELEASE'
    testCompile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.3.7.Final'
    testCompile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.13'
    testCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jstl', version: '4.0.1'
    testCompile group: 'javax.validation', name: 'validation-api', version: '2.0.1.Final'
    testCompile group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'javax.persistence-api', version: '2.2'
    testCompile group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'persistence-api', version: '1.0.2'
    testCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'servlet-api', version: '3.0-alpha-1'
}
```

After I update `build.gradle` file (for example after add/remove dependency):

I get unresolved symbols in every file:

[image]

Comment: would it be `compile group`

Comment: you are right, it works..

Comment: writing same as answer and would appreciate if you accept as answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `testCompile group` group to `compile group`